# matching impedance of stm32f4-discovery board's DCMI to image sensor data line

Tags: impedance

Could you please let me know how to find input impedance of STM32F407 DCMI pins?

I'm designing a camera module using sony's IMX224 image sensor. In the future this module will be connected to STM32F407 discovery board. Thus I need to consider the impedances of them. According to its data sheet the IMX224 sensor has output impedance of 50Ω typically at high data rate. But I wonder how large input impedance the STM32F4 board has. Especially I'm interested in using DCMI to get data from the sensor. But the data sheet of STM32F407 and user manual of the STM32F4-discovery board don't specify its input impedance.

links: datasheets
     http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00037051.pdf
      http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/cn/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00039084.pdf

Comment: The input impedance is the impedance of pull up/down resistors, I guess.

Comment: Look at the circuit diagram in the link you posted. Then check what connections are being made to the particular pins. Note that info down i.e. pull-ups and pull-downs. Then go to the actual data sheet of the device and see what it tells you is the input impedance. The final impedance is what the data sheet tells you in parallel with any pull-up/downs.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 1. I couldn't find any additional resistors in the schematics of discovery board. 2. But for the MCU itelf the I/O characteristic shows 'Weak pull-up equivalent resistor' and 'Weak pull-down equivalent resistor'. I guess you meant these values. Would you please confirm if I understood what you meant?